# Default in list partition

Tags: oracle

I have the next doubt:

Default in list partition can be used only in the last partition? And in the penultimate partition? And can be allocated the null value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT`, by definition can be used only in one partition, and it must be the last partition:

```
$ oerr ora 14318
14318, 00000, "DEFAULT partition must be last partition specified"
// *Cause:  A partition description follows the one describing the default
//          partition
// *Action: Ensure that the DEFAULT partition is the last partition description
```

You can specify a seperate partition for nulls. Example:

[Creating a List-Partitioned Table With a Default Partition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/vldbg/partition-create-tables-indexes.html#GUID-8928C3B0-2F83-4213-B765-EFBBF0372F64)

> Unlike range partitioning, with list partitioning, there is no
>   apparent sense of order between partitions.
>
> You can also specify a default partition into which rows that do not
>   map to any other partition are mapped. If a default partition were
>   specified in the preceding example, the state CA would map to that
>   partition.
>
> Example 4-6 creates table sales_by_region and partitions it using the
>   list method. The first two PARTITION clauses specify physical
>   attributes, which override the table-level defaults. The remaining
>   PARTITION clauses do not specify attributes and those partitions
>   inherit their physical attributes from table-level defaults. A default
>   partition is also specified.
>
> Example 4-6 Creating a list-partitioned table with a default partition
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales_by_region (item# INTEGER, qty INTEGER, 
>              store_name VARCHAR(30), state_code VARCHAR(2),
>              sale_date DATE)
>      STORAGE(INITIAL 10K NEXT 20K) TABLESPACE tbs5 
>      PARTITION BY LIST (state_code) 
>      (
>      PARTITION region_east
>         VALUES ('MA','NY','CT','NH','ME','MD','VA','PA','NJ')
>         STORAGE (INITIAL 8M) 
>         TABLESPACE tbs8,
>      PARTITION region_west
>         VALUES ('CA','AZ','NM','OR','WA','UT','NV','CO')
>         NOLOGGING,
>      PARTITION region_south
>         VALUES ('TX','KY','TN','LA','MS','AR','AL','GA'),
>      PARTITION region_central 
>         VALUES ('OH','ND','SD','MO','IL','MI','IA'),
>      PARTITION region_null
>         VALUES (NULL),
>      PARTITION region_unknown
>         VALUES (DEFAULT)
>      );
> ```

If you do no specify a separate null partition, then those rows go into the `DEFAULT`partition.